# Nestjs as API gateway + Moleculer as microservice

Tags: node.js, microservices, nestjs, api-gateway, moleculer

I'm very new in microservices, I was a wonder to know that is there any way to call a moleculer action from nestjs gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-moleculer?activeTab=versions

To inject a service broker and call moleculer actiona or define new ones inside nest

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33058085)